# how to serialize a spark sql row object into byte array?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql `Row` object and its `StructType` as schema. How can I serialize it into a `Array[Byte]`?

I tried to write this object into a byte stream, because I saw `Row` type extends `Serializable`. But I think it is not efficient because the schema is not used, so the result might not be compact.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the method `Row.getAs[T](fieldName:String)`, example :

```
// generate a row
val df = Seq(Array(1.toByte)).toDF("bytes")
val row = df.collect().head
// extract field 
val arr: Array[Byte] = row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("bytes")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found the solution, it is just use writeObject to write the row into a byte output stream, schema is known because I create the row by `Row.fromTuple`

Comment: @XiangZhang Can you answer your own question then? `writeObject` is exactly what you need.